# Ignoring NaN values in a scikit clustering algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nan, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I've used an agglomerative algorithm to cluster a factorized dataframe (which is working). The NaN values show up as -1 in this dataframe, but I don't want to include them as input-data for the algorithm. I think I've to set some sort of a boundary where I specify that only values =>0 should be taken into account, but I'm not sure how to get this done. Below I show my algorithm code and a part of the output of dataframe z.

```
z=df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None,distance_threshold=(10), affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
cluster.fit_predict(z)
```

Part of the dataframe z:

```
0       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
1       0       0       0       0  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
2       0       0       0       0  ...        1       -1       -1          -1
3       0       0       0       0  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
4       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
5       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
6       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
7       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
8       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
9       0       0       0       0  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
10      0       1       1       1  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
11      0       1       1       1  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
12      0       2       1       2  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
13      0       2       1       2  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
14      0       3       1       3  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
15      0       3       1       3  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
16      1       4       1       4  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
17      1       4       1       4  ...        1       -1       -1          -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Before creating `z`, call `DataFrame.dropna()`. You can read more on [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna).

```py
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```